# Prove a function is surjective using Z3

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm trying to understand how to prove efficiently using Z3 that a somewhat simple function `f : u32 -> u32` is bijective:

```py
def f(n):
    for i in range(10):
        n *= 3
        n &= 0xFFFFFFFF # Let's treat this like a 4 byte unsigned number
        n ^= 0xDEADBEEF
    return n
```

I know already it is bijective since it's obtained by composition of bijective functions, so this is more of a computational question.

Now, knowing the domain and codomain are finite and of the same size, I thought of first doing this by asking Z3 to find a counterexample to it being injective:

```py
N = BitVec('N', 32)
M = BitVec('M', 32)
solve(N != M, f(N) == f(M))
```

However this is taking quite a while (> 10 minutes but shut it down after), and reasonably so, since the search space is pretty much 64 bit and the function may be quite complex to reason about since it mixes a lot of multiplication with binary arithmetic, so I wondered whether it was possible instead to prove it by surjection, maybe resulting faster.

Whether that's actually faster or if there's even a way to solve this efficiently yet may be another question, however I was stuck on thinking how to prove it by surjection, that is ask Z3 to find an `M` such that `f(N) != M forall N`.

Is this anywhere different from proving injectivity?

How do I state it in Z3's python bindings?

Is it possible to remove existential qualifiers out of the surjective statement at all?

Are there more efficient ways to prove that a function is bijective? Since for something like this a bruteforce search may be more efficient, as the memory required shouldn't be a lot for 32 bit vectors, but the approach surely wouldn't work on 64 bit input/outputs.

Comment: The naive way of encoding injectivity admits a quadratic number of instantiations, whereas an indirect encoding via inverse functions only admits a linear number: see https://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/, section Quantifiers, subsection Multi-patterns. Maybe that gets you a bit further.

Comment: Thanks! I was about to write something silly like a for loop inverting every single value until it couldn't

Comment: @MalteSchwerhoff Quantifiers and patterns are indeed a fine idea to try! My experience with them has been rather fickle, unfortunately. The triggers are usually hard to hit, and they do require uninterpreted functions I believe. (So, maybe you can prove something like if an uninterpreted function `f` is bijective, so is its composition with itself 10 times. I'm not sure if you can do a direct proof of this particular function here.) However, if you do manage to do this proof, I'd love to see how it's done. It would be quite educational, please do share your findings.

Comment: "The injectivity of a function over finite sets of the same size also proves its surjectivity" : This OK, AGREE. (solve(N!=M, f(N) == f(M)) - FINE for injectivity and if finite surjective). But how finite sets are defined (just take 10 points and see f(n) != f(m) and say don't care co-domain is finite and same cardinality. So put the function definition f(x)=x, take 10 points as discrete_Domanin and that's my proof using a miracle tool ! Very well to use whatever suits better(no issues here) but maybe what you are doing have no usage (more of learning Z3) ... Any way GOOD LUCK!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd write the surjectivity as follows:

```py
N = BitVec('N', 32)
M = BitVec('M', 32)
s = Solver()
s.add(ForAll([N], f(N) != M))

r = s.check()
if r == sat:
    print(s.model())
else:
    print(r)
```

Unfortunately adding quantifiers to bit-vectors make the logic undecidable in general, and z3 simply gives up after about 10 seconds on my machine:

```
unknown
```

In general, adding quantifiers is just going to make the problem very difficult for z3 (or any other SMT solver for that matter). Your original encoding of:

```
solve(N!=M, f(N) == f(M))
```

is probably the best way to encode this problem. And in fact, if you change the range from 10 to something smaller (I tried up-to 3), z3 answers `unsat` relatively quickly. But obviously the solver time will go exponentially as the number of iterations in your function `f` increases.

An SMT solver is probably not the best tool to prove a property like this. You can surely express such constraints, but at best you'll get `unknown` as an answer and at worst it'll loop forever. A proper theorem prover (like Isabelle, HOL, Coq, ACL2, etc.) would provide a much better (at the cost of being less automated) platform to do these proofs.

Comment: > A proper theorem prover would provide a much better platform to do these proofs.

I'm interested in Lean but haven't yet found the time to learn it, are you sure these theorem provers can reason in terms of mixed math-binary operations somewhat nicely? Ideally combining something like Z3 (which can trivially prove the case for n = 1 here) would be cool.

If you have more resources in general about your last paragraph I'd appreciate it, althought I am surprised Z3 can't solve this problem incrementally, like making it first solve for n=1, then n=2 and so on.

Comment: "solve(N!=M, f(N) == f(M))" wonder if this check for surjectivity! Do not think so ! ... Further more I doubt that here are any tools in any languages that could provide the check, maybe some heuristic algorithms ...One hint, f:C->D and where is D ??? maybe f(C) == D needed ... just wonder

Comment: @mgostIH People have proved amazing math theorems using theorem provers, and the definition of "nice" really depends on how much automation you can get from already built theories. Isabelle has bit-vector reasoning (http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~jeremy/pubs/l4/avocs/word.pdf) and lots of math proofs were done in HOL-Light: https://github.com/jrh13/hol-light, amongst others. Note that these theorem provers can use SMT solvers as oracle's these days, so you kind of get support of z3 automatically. Note that SMT solvers do not do induction, but you can use the theorem prover for that nicely.

Comment: @TraianGEICU Your comment doesn't make much sense to me; but this is a question about z3/z3py; not about general math. Automated theorem proving has come a long ways, and the encoding of surjectivity is just fine. A future version of the tool might as well solve it out-of-the-box; it's just not within reach right now.

Comment: His task was to prove surjectivity using a particular tool. How to prove something if what is asked is wrong ???, not surjectivity here. First it's need for problem to be well encoding, this require MATH !(here the output is what-ever wanted to call it but no related to surjectivity). Language is second ! More over it's up to you to consider as magical as you wanted those SOLVERS, but there are no miracle inside (just math) and even with-out them math theory goes further (they are not necessary needed but could be used to get same things as on papers ...)

Comment: @TraianGEICU
>"solve(N!=M, f(N) == f(M))" wonder if this check for surjectivity! Do not think so!

As I wrote on the question, this was the statement for injectivity. The injectivity of a function over finite sets of the same size also proves its surjectivity and vice versa. Z3 is a theorem prover, so yes, it can prove that there's no counterexample to the non injectivity of a function, proving its injective.

I'd ask you to at least motivate the downvote, alias' answer is spot on.